# Analytics Ecommerce: is there a way to add custom parameters at item level to the add_payment_info event? Android app

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

in my Android application I want to record analytics when payment information is added along with the cart items, when a button is pressed. I want to collect custom parameters at item level that are not predefined by Google in the "add_payment_info" event because I need to record more information than what Google allows me with its parameters. But I'm having problems because the new custom parameters don't appear in the DebugView.

Is there any way to do this?

I've read the google documentation about creating custom dimensions and create an item-scoped custom dimension and I've tried what it says there without success. I'm not sure if that's what I need.

Here is the documentation:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209?hl=en&sjid=6197029095991637761-EU#zippy=%2Ccrear-una-dimensi%C3%B3n-personalizada-relativa-al-art%C3%ADculo

This is a list in kotlin code of some of the analytics I collect:

```
firebaseAnalytics.logEvent("add_payment_info") {
    param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CURRENCY, EUR)
    param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, 100)
    param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEMS, arrayOf(Bundle().apply {
        putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "SAMPLE")
        putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "SAMPLE")
        putString("product_size", "M") // custom parameter
        putString("product_id_with_size", "000000.M") // custom parameter
        // ...more parameters
    }))
}
```

If you notice, the last two item-level parameters are custom that I want to collect in the "add_payment_info" event.

Doing it as I show in the code above doesn't work because DebugView doesn't show me those two custom parameters.

This is an image of the DebugView:
[DebugView not showing the custom parameters in the "add_payment_info" event.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOeI6.png)

Another image with the custom parameters in the custom dimensions:
[Custom parameters added to custom dimensions at item level.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQ2RY.png)

I have also noticed that the Android logcat shows me an error when I upload the analytics.

```
Item array not supported on client's version of Google Play Services (Android Only): add_payment_info, Bundle[{...
Item array not supported on client's version of Google Play Services (Android Only): add_payment_info, Bundle[{...
```

I don't know what else I can try and I can't find much documentation about it.
Can I add custom parameters at item level to the "add_payment_info" event? If so, how can I do it?

Thank you very much, sorry for my english.